# Print a capital name, given a country input in an interactive C console application

Tags: c, arrays, string, runtime-error, console-application

```
void capital()  //print the capitals of the choosen countries
{
     system("cls");
     struct country
     {
        char name[40];
        char capital[40];

     };

    struct country cont_list[100]=
    {
        "amman","jordan",
        "amsterdam","nertherlands",
        "athens","greece",
        "bangkok","thailand",
        "beijing","china",
        "berlin","germany",
        "cairo","egypt",
        "canberra","australia",
        "copenhagen","denmark",
        "dhaka","bangladesh",
        "doha","qatar",
        "dublin","ireland",
        "helsinki","finland",
        "jakarta","indonesia",
        "kabul","afghanistan",
        "kingston","jamaica",
        "kuala lumpur","malaysia",
        "london","unitedkingdom",
        "lisbon","portugal",
        "madrid","spain",
        "manila","philippines",
        "mexico city","mexico",
        "moscow","russia",
        "nairobi","kenya",
        "nassau","bahamas",
        "new delhi","india",
        "ottawa","canada",
        "oslo","norway",
        "paris","france",
        "prague","czech republic",
        "pretoria","africa",
        "pristina","kosovo",
        "pyonyang","north korea",
        "riyadh","saudi arabia",
        "rome","italy",
        "colombo","sri lanka",
        "santiago","chile",
        "seoul","south korea",
        "singapore","singapore",
        "sofia","bulgaria",
        "stockholm","sweden",
        "suva","fiji",
        "taipei","taiwan",
        "tashkent","uzbekistan",
        "tbilisi","georgia",
        "tehran","iran",
        "tirana","albania",
        "tokyo","japan",
        "tripoli","libya",
        "tunis","tunisia",
        "ulaanbaatar","mongolia",
        "vienna","austria",
        "vientiane","laos",
        "warsaw","poland",
        "washington d.c","united states of america",
        "wellington","new zealand",
        "zagreb","crotia",
    };

    int i,choice;
    int pos;
    char inval[20];

    system("cls");
    printf("Enter the name of the Country : ");
    gets(inval);
    pos=-1;

    for(i=0;i<=50;i++)
    {   
        if(strcmp(inval,cont_list[i].name)==0)
           pos=i;   
    }

    if(pos>-1)      
    {
        printf("capital= ");
        printf("%x", cont_list[pos].capital);
        getch();
    }
    else
        printf("\n\t Sorry, Country not in database");

    askover();
    system("pause");

    // End function
}
```

Write an interactive, menu-driven program C program that will accept the name of a country as
input and display the corresponding capital, and vice versa. Design the program so that it
executes repeatedly, until the word End is entered as input. Please add more countries to the
list (at least 50).

Comment: So, you want us to do your homework for you?

Comment: no. i just want to ask how to manipulate string and compared it  with another two constant string.

Comment: i just show my work to show you my effort in trying this..

Comment: anyone who understand my problem. im begging you. i've been searching like 2 weeks

Comment: so what you're trying to say is that for 2 weeks you couldnt find a way to 'manipulate' string (whatever it means) or compare strings in C? That is impossible to find a tutorial, manual, instruction, existing questions on SO, anything on basic operations of one of the most common and well described programming languages ever? Well, apparently nobody believes you, and you should be ashamed. It's not even a minute on google to find a working example and you didnt even bother to format your question properly

Comment: *"I just want to ask how to manipulate string and compared it with another two constant string"* - then you should actually ask this in your question, rather than just leave it at the assignment statement.

Comment: Your existing code **already** *"manipulates string"* and *compares with another string* - make sure you understand what all of the code you've been given does before trying to extend it.

Comment: sorry for my not concerning before asking a question... thank you everyone that comment. i'll be better next time.

Answer (score 0):

If you problem is to compare strings you may want to switch the order of your variables inside `struct country`. That is Amman is the capital of Jordan and not vice versa. Otherwise `strcmp` will never return 0.

Comment: If that solved your issue please flag the answer as accepted